# Alert an enemy with Microphone input C#, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code that takes microphone input and converts it into a float number. Now, I need to convert that input into a radius in a game. That radius defines players range. Suppose, I yelled into microphone and I got the radius. If an enemy is within the range of radius, the enemy is alerted. Can someone please, help me do it. Do I create a new script for that, or do I need to do it in the player controller?

Comment: This isn't a Coding Service - you need to write the code yourself. If you run into specific problems (that will likely help someone else) please post. Answering this I dont think is going to help anyone but you unfortunately. That said, you will need to write code, 1. the microphone voice detection, 2. the speech-to-text, 3. text to radius conversion, 4. Publish/Subscribe players to each others radius events, 5. Alert users within one and others vicinity.

Comment: You dont need to do anything special with recognition.  The radius is simply proportional to the volume level recorded from the microphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you have one script running via your player entity or on a 'scene controller' group (added solely to run background scripts) that contains your 'mic listener' script.  Then on your enemy prefab add a 'mic data receiver' script.

1) Use FindComponent<> from your 'mic data receiver' script to locate and retrieve volumes from the 'mic listener' script, or; 
2) Use a pub/sub message aggregator in the 'mic listener' script that broadcasts a mic data mesage, and then have your enemy's 'mic listener' class subscribe to this information and calculate in/out of range based on volume Vs. distance.

Sounds like your underlying question is about communication between objects and how to organize 'services' / information producers Vs. arbitrary game entities / discreet information consumers.
Do some searches on best practices for inter-object communication and you'll have a better answer from the Unity team's documentation than I could ever provide.

Good Luck!